# Is the bigbluebutton-api-ruby (1.2.0) gem compatible with BigBlueButton 0.81?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, bigbluebutton

I am using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3.

I have configured my BigBlueButtonServer (version 0.81) and I want to connect it with a Ruby on Rails application where I have used these two gems:
1. bigbluebutton-api-ruby (1.2.0); and,
2. bigbluebutton_rails (1.3.0).

In the RubyGems documentation it says that it supports BigBlueButton 0.8, but does not say anything about 0.81. Has anybody used the latest BigBlueButton server (version 0.81) with these gems? Are they compatible with this version?

Comment: yes it works for both 0.8 and 0.81

Answer (score 1):

Since version [1.3.0 (11/May/2014)](https://github.com/mconf/bigbluebutton-api-ruby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rdoc#130), bigbluebutton-api-ruby is compatible with BigBlueButton 0.81.

As one of the developers of the gem, I can say that support to 0.81 took some time to be included in a version of bigbluebutton-api-ruby, but it was for a long time available in a branch that already included most of the features needed to use it with BigBlueButton 0.81.
Even though using branches instead of finished versions is not really recommended, in some cases it can be useful to take a look at the available branches and try them out to have access to new features faster.

Comment: For bigbluebutton-api-ruby 1.2.0 everything was fine. Now I am using version 1.3.0 I am facing error. Please provide some solution. I have posted my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188503/unable-to-fill-data-from-seed-file

Comment: BigBlueButton Server 0.81 (1554)
Kernel version: 2.6.32-042stab083.2
Distribution: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (64-bit)                        Memory: 6144 MB , etc were configuration when i used first time bigbluebutton. That time used bigbluebutton-api-ruby 1.2.0, bigbluebutton_rails 1.3.0. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have given up using it, it is suppose to work best with 0.7, no 0.81 support. Do it yourself, anyway the bigbluebutton API is extremely simple

Comment: thanks, i will try with 0.8 version hope it works fine